# Reminder on Event List

Tags: list, power-automate

I found some other posts on setting reminders for event lists and used those to get the basic flow working. But I'm running into an issue with how I've built it that causes multiple notifications to be sent out if someone edits the list.

I'm doing a simple flow triggered by adding or editing the list that sends a Teams message when the event starts. To accomplish that I'm using the Delay Until step and setting it to be the date/time column of the list

[image: flow]

But if someone then edits the list and changes something like the time or description, it doesn't cancel or edit the pending message and instead queues another message to go out. So, if someone adds an item to the list for today at 13:00, that message gets queued up. But then a few minutes later, they edit the list item and set it to 14:00 instead. It queues up a second message. Then I get one message at 13:00 and another at 14:00.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior, once you add or modify an item, a new flow is initiated with a flow ID, so in your second edit, you already have one flow running and a new one has been initiated, so you get two messages.

To solve this issue, you have first to cancel the first flow by getting its flow ID using this expression

```
workflow()?['run']['name']
```

> You have to save it in your list with each trigger to can get it.

Then, when a new item is edited,  you have to use `Cancel flow Run` action to cancel the current running flow by ID.